# UITextfield unresponsive. UITextfield embedded in alert isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I am working in a table view and I want the user to be able to click a button that brings up an alert with a text field. They enter a string in the text field, press enter, and that string appears as a row in the table. Here is my code for getting the alert and text field to appear when the top right plus icon is pressed. Once I press it in the simulator, the app becomes unresponsive, there is no cursor in the text field, and I can't type using the simulated keyboard or my actual keyboard. Here is the code and an image:

```
@IBAction func addButtonPress(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
    var textField = UITextField()
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Category", style: .default) { (action) in
        
        let newCategory = Category(context: self.context)
        newCategory.name = textField.text!
        
        self.categoryArray.append(newCategory)
        
        self.saveCategories()
        
    }
    
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new category"
        textField = alertTextField
    }
    
    alert.addAction(action)
    
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is `var textField` doing in the story?

Comment: I set textField to the alertTextField in that addTextField closure.

Comment: And I'm saying why do you do that. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I was following a tutorial. What's a better alternative?

Comment: Better alternative to do _what_, is what I'm asking. What is your goal here? An alert has a text field, you don't need to talk about another one.

Comment: Currently, the text field in the alert isn't working; I can't type anything into it or press Add Category. Are you saying I can just delete the var textField?

Comment: Well that is certainly the first thing I would do, as it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead. Basically it gets the value of the first text field in your alert.

```swift
@IBAction func addButtonPress(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Category", style: .default) { (action) in
        guard let categoryName = alert.textFields?.first?.text else { return }
        
        let newCategory = Category(context: self.context)
        newCategory.name = categoryName
        
        self.categoryArray.append(newCategory)
        self.saveCategories()
        
    }
    
    alert.addTextField { alertTextField in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new category"
    }
    
    alert.addAction(action)
    
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```